# Tiny Death Star assignments and the galactic registry changes

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have been playing tiny Death Star for awhile and about two weeks ago I completed all the assignments on the imperial levels.  I thought maybe I needed to add more imperial levels to get new assignments, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Also, the galactic registry changed to normal bitizens and I lost the deep core bitizen.

I tried to find a solution to this problem:  one person said to delete the game and start over, but this was for Game Center issues not this one.  Someone else asked about this issue, but the question wasn't worded right I guess but one reply said it is an Apple problem at the end but it didn't say if the person found a solution.

I want to know if I should restart from beginning which is okay with me or is it just a programming issue with the operating systems on apple products and hope for a fix from Disney?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Tiny Death Star has been [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star):

> The game was removed from the Apple App Store and Google Play Store by Disney in October 2014.

If you are unable to workaround the bug/issue by restarting the application or your device, then there's nothing we can do: there is **no fix coming**.

As you are playing on iOS, I would not recommend uninstalling the game if you wish to keep it. Only those who had [previously downloaded the game on Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star#Bugs) can still redownload & access the game.

Comment: Note: this answer is a [community-proposed solution](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13064/28182) for unresolved Tiny Death Star bug questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Registry is all wrong! I emailed Star Wars site and they advised me to keep an eye on apps store. When error is fixed new update will be avabilàble. However, this was 3 weeks ago and I sm still waiting

Comment: I emailed them also about it and they said might have too many apps open.  I just keep playing since it's not that big of a problem. I was just kind of curious since it seems to be an Apple thing from what I've seen.